# How to zoom a div in on page load with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to make a div zoom-in when the page loads? Like when you install a new app in Chrome, it brings you to the new tab page and zooms in the new app. It looks nice.

Anyone know how to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's one way to zoom with jQuery

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7cn8/)

set starting sizes (and position offset with `top` & `left`) in your CSS:

```
#zoom-box {
    background: #7d7e7d;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%);
    border-radius:10px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:relative;
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
    border:solid 4px yellow;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
```

then size everything up with a jQuery `animate()` method

```
$('#zoom-box').animate({
    width:'300px',
    height:'300px',
    top:'0',
    left:'0',
    'font-size':'50px',
    'line-height':'300px'
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly. Thanks :) Is there anyway to get the background-image to resize with it? Like this div has a background-image and it doesn't resize. Is there anything I can add to that to make the background-image grow also? (it is like already the size and the div just grows but it doesn't look that good.)

Comment: You can resize the image while zooming if you use an `<img>` element see this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/D7cn8/6/) by setting width to `100%`... and actually with CSS3 you can set `background-size` to `100%` as well [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/D7cn8/7/) but not sure which browsers support that (tested/worked in Chrome 14)

Comment: Thanks. It's actually already an `<img>` but with a background-image. The reason for this is so when the user tries to right click and save it, they are saving `blank.gif` instead of the actual image. I will probably just change it to a regular `<img>` because the site will most likely be viewed by IE 8 users, sadly. I wish IE could just be CSS compliance with everything like a regular browser. Anyway, thanks so much for your help! This will make the site really look good. By the way, the site is http://weebuild1.yolasite.com/ The image that I'm making zoom in is the monitor.

Comment: Small help after some amount of time it should be reset to normal state and should rotate for that what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You will need to zoom-in everything inside the DIV, like images, increase text size, etc...

Maybe there are zooming plugins for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:1em;
}

.big {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:2em;
}
```

**JQuery (with JQueryUI):**

```
$(function(){
      $('#my_div').addClass("big",500).removeClass("big",500);
});
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tjRvn/

Unfortunately `addClass()` with the duration is not working in Chrome tonight. Weird :/