# OSX Snow Leopard start screen page transition with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-transitions

Have a pretty straight forward question about page transitions with jQuery. I would like to copy the transition that my Mac does when the the it goes from booting to showing the desktop. I would like to use jQuery for this. Has anybody stumbled upon some resources that cold help me in the redirection?

You can see a video on the transition I'm looking for here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-I9F4JswFXI

Answer (score 0):

This is using CSS3 transitions, but will fallback gracefully for other browsers.
Basically we set a full page wrapper div and make in invisible and slightly smaller. Then when we enact the `.show` class it will transition to full size and full opacity.

We then trigger this on page load, and you should be almost exactly like lion. :)

**CSS**

```
#fullPageWrapper{
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
    -moz-transition:all 1s;
    -ms-transition:all 1s;
    -o-transition:all 1s;
    transition:all 1s;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.8);
    -o-transform:scale(0.8);
    transform:scale(0.8);
    opacity:0;
}

#fullPageWrapper.show{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
     $(window).on('load', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
              $('#fullPageWrapper').addClass('show');
          },16);         
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the available resource. But you can create it using jQuery Fade(for hiding the startup screen), Load(for loading image content using AJAX) and Zoom (for enlarging the image on startup).

These links will help you :

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/load/

[How to zoom a div in on page load with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073422/how-to-zoom-a-div-in-on-page-load-with-jquery)