# How to make a zoomIn animation for two images in a single div in html

Tags: html, css, image, animation, zooming

I am creating a index page with some animation in which i need a single div which has two images for which i want a zoomIn animation using css(for both the images, one is left and another one is right). Please someone help me i am new to the website development.

Answer (score 1):

To your css file add:

```
your-div-class img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
your-div-class img:hoover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
            transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

Comment: i dont need a hover animation but i need a zoomIn animation like this reference  [link](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Actually your reference shows the same thing, just using keyframes. If you need the animation to work in a page load, for example, you might want to use `animate.css`

Comment: i have use that one but its not working when the page loads

Comment: can you please some reference code for using zoomin animation for a single div which contains two images placed left and right

Comment: Maybe that is what you are looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073422/how-to-zoom-a-div-in-on-page-load-with-jquery

Comment: Yes i was looking that one but still its not working for me

Comment: <div class="zoomIn img-responsive">
   <img src="images/Daf.png" style="height: 100px; width: 300px;" class="image left" />
   <img src="images/Daf.png" style="height: 100px; width: 300px;" class="image right" />
   </div>                                                                                                                       I need a zoomIn animation for this div with two images simultaneously when a page load.

Comment: Based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073422/how-to-zoom-a-div-in-on-page-load-with-jquery
Try to focus the jQuery to IMG instead of the DIV.